# How to access the Openshift cluster using .kubeconfig file

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

I have to authenticate the openshift cluster via .kube/config file. For that, I have generated a x509 client certificate and key using OpenSSL.I converted that certificate into .pem format using the following command *x509 -in xyz.crt -out xyz.pem -outform PEM* I had generated one .kube/config file for openshift authentication I put the ca.pem, xyz.pem and xyz_key.pem into that openshift .kube/config file.But I am 
facing Error like error *tls- failed to find any PEM data in certificate input*

Kinds regard and thank you for your patience.